# Prove: $\forall a,b\in \mathbf{R^+}, \exists m\in \mathbf{N}$ such that $(m-1)a\leq b \leq ma$.

Tags: analysis

Prove: $\forall a,b\in \mathbf{R^+}, \exists m\in \mathbf{N}$ such that $(m-1)a\leq b \leq ma$.

**Proof:**

Since $a,b \in \mathbf{R^+}$ we have that $\frac{b}{a} > 0$. Let $A = \{n \in \mathbf{N} : \frac{b}{a} < n  \}$. It's obvious that $A$ is non empty and is bounded below. Let $\inf{A} = m$, then we have that $\frac{b}{a}\leq m$. Suppose $m = 1$, then clearly $0\leq \frac{b}{a} \leq 1$. Suppose $m > 1$. Since $m$ is the smallest natural number greater than $\frac{b}{a}$, it is implied that $m-1 \leq \frac{b}{a} \leq m$. Since $a>0$ multiplying the inequality by $a$ gives $(m-1)a\leq b \leq ma$ as desired.

Is this a valid proof?

EDIT: I should say let $\min{A} = m$ since I cannot show that $\inf(A) \in A$.

Comment: it seems alright assuming that $\mathbb R^+$ does not include $0$. Also, $m \in \mathbb N^*$, but it might just be your notations.

Comment: What does it mean to prove a statement that is so obvious?  Unless this is actually an exercise on using the axioms of real numbers to prove it, the proof is simply "hey look at this obvious theorem.  It's true because it is obvious".

Comment: @WNG: Yes, my notation means exactly that.

Comment: @DanielV: I've always been taught that math is axiomatic, and that it's usually never enough to say that something is obvious.

Comment: @SOULed_Outt So you think the answer to this question should use hilbert style derivations, or fitch style deductions?  Math is the process of reducing questionable statements to less questionable statements.  If something is obvious, then there are no less questionable assumptions, unless you are actually doing an exercise in manipulating axiomatic theory.

Comment: @DanielV: Isn't manipulating axiomatic theory the same as the process of reducing questionable statements to less questionable statements? I suppose manipulation axiomatic theory is the point of the courses I've taken.

Comment: @SOULed_Outt In a sense yes, but the question is different.  If a statement $T$ is "obviously true", it still may not be obvious that it is within the span of a given axiomatic theory.  In that regard, the theorem you are actually proving is "$T$ is spanned by axiom set $A$", and the more obvious pillars is the proof itself, not the axiom set.  In any case, a proof only is meaningful if you are reducing a statement to less questionable statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(m-1)a\le b\le ma\iff ma-a\le b\le ma\Rightarrow -a\le0$ wich  is obvious.

Thus the statement of the post it is true.